# Save the data in txt file without brackets and comma (Python)

Tags: python

My source data is appended in the following array:

```
x,y,w,h = track_window
listing.append([x,y]):
```

where

```
x = [300, 300, 300, 296, 291, 294, 299, 284, 303, 323, 334, 343, 354, 362, 362, 362, 360, 361, 351]
```

and

```
y = [214, 216, 214, 214, 216, 216, 215, 219, 217, 220, 218, 218, 222, 222, 222, 223, 225, 224, 222]
```

So x values should be written to a text file and after that y values without comma and brackets like this form, where there is an empty space between every two numbers and (8) numbers in each row.

x:

```
300 300 300 296 291 294 299 284 

303 323 334 343 354 362 362 362 

360 361 351
```

y:

```
300 300 300 296 291 294 299 284 

303 323 334 343 354 362 362 362 

360 361 351
```

How can i achieve it?

What i did:

```
with open('text.txt', 'rb') as f:
   val = pickle.load(f)
   for i in range(2):
      if i==0:
      #def Extract(lst):
        a = [item[0] for item in val] 
        #return a        
      if i==1:
      #def Extract(lst):
        b = [item[1] for item in val] 
      #return b
  
      #print(val)
      #print(Extract(val)) 
      print(a)
      print(b)

  f.close()
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to see what you have tried.  Nonetheless, this will work for you.

```
def write_in_chunks(f, lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        chunk = lst[i : i+n]
        f.write(" ".join(str(val) for val in chunk) + "\n")

        
x = [300, 300, 300, 296, 291, 294, 299, 284, 303, 323, 334, 343, 354, 362, 362, 362, 360, 361, 351]

y = [214, 216, 214, 214, 216, 216, 215, 219, 217, 220, 218, 218, 222, 222, 222, 223, 225, 224, 222]

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    write_in_chunks(f, x, 8)
    write_in_chunks(f, y, 8)
```

Creates `output.txt` containing

```
300 300 300 296 291 294 299 284
303 323 334 343 354 362 362 362
360 361 351
214 216 214 214 216 216 215 219
217 220 218 218 222 222 222 223
225 224 222
```

Adding extra blank lines in the output is left as an exercise for the reader... (hint: see where existing newlines are written).

Comment: Thank you @alaniwi, i added what i did. but your solution save me a lot of trouble